# firestore in china:Unavailable: failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: firebase, nginx, google-cloud-firestore, nginx-reverse-proxy

I cannot use Firebase normally, so I use a proxy software. However, when I try to use the Firestore service, I still get an error message: '2023-05-25 12:04:58.539759+0800 Flash Chat iOS13[11021:103045] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WriteStream (7fad6893f628) Stream error: 'Unavailable: failed to connect to all addresses'. I think my code is fine, so I would like to ask if anyone has a solution to this issue. Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqlu8.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xalRU.png)

How to solve this problem，thanks!